# Where to provide necessary Django environment variables in a CI/CD pipeline using Docker and GitHub Actions

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have a Django application that I use GitHub Actions to deploy to an Azure Kubernetes Cluster,

When I run the app locally using `docker-compose up` I get the following error screen;

[image]

Traceback log

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://0.0.0.0:8000/

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.8.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'djoser',
 'oauth2_provider',
 'social_django',
 'drf_yasg',
 'core']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 113, in __call__
    response = self.process_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
    host = request.get_host()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 137, in get_host
    raise DisallowedHost(msg)

Exception Type: DisallowedHost at /
Exception Value: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '0.0.0.0:8000'. You may need to add '0.0.0.0' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

I'm unsure where to provide these Environment variables of course by keeping the sensitive ones hidden.

**The variables found in .dev.env**

```
DEBUG="True"
SECRET_KEY="...86hoe@14y6)en"
ALLOWED_HOSTS="localhost,127.0.0.1 [::1]"
DATABASE_HOST="postgres"
DATABASE_USER="postgres"
DATABASE_NAME="postgres"
DATABASE_PASSWORD="postgres"
```

Below are my Dockerfile and docker-compose files;

**docker-compose**

```
--- 
version: "3.7"
services: 
  postgres: 
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    image: "postgres:12"
    networks:
      - internal
  web: 
    build: "."
    container_name: identityservice
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    environment: 
      - DEBUG=1
      - "SECRET_KEY=\"#e...20m7rxh*%)ki(*=\""
    ports: 
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - internal
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes: 
      - "./src/:/app/"

networks:
  internal:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8-slim


# Set working directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Set environment variables
# Prevents Python from writing pyc files to disc (equivalent to python -B option)
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# Prevents Python from buffering stdout and stderr (equivalent to python -u option)
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install django-environ

COPY ./src .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Sorry if this is very straight forward or basic. I appreciate your help, Thanks

Comment: Have you tied a pipenv shell? or just and env.py file with all the variables?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have not tried pipenv or env.py, I'm not sure where and how to implement it in my workflow. Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

I found a tool called [Kustomize](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/secretgenerator/) it seems a better way at providing necessary environment variables and secrets for your container at runtime. I'm going to try it out and report back here if it works for me.